# Is there a way to convert any generic Numeric into a Double?

Tags: swift, generics

So I have a method that has 3 different types of arguments that could come in:

`Int32`, `Int` and `Double`.  So the idea was to use generics to minimize the interface

```
func resetProgressBarChunks<T:Numeric>(originalIterationCount: T) {
    guard let iCount = originalIterationCount as? Double else {return}
```

But what I have realized, is at runtime, the `Int32` and `Int` arguments will actually fail that `guard let`.  It makes sense, it was just wishful thinking on my part.

But if I try to simply cast a `Numeric` into a double, the compiler will bark:

```
func resetProgressBarChunks<T:Numeric>(originalIterationCount: T) {
    guard let iCount = Double(originalIterationCount) else {return}
```

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument of type '(T)'

Which I suppose also makes sense, because there is no initializer for Double that takes a Generic.

So it looks like I'm about to be forced to write 3 methods with different parameter types.  The `Int32` and `Int` parameter types would just cast into a `Double` and then call the `Double` method.  Is this really the best way?  I really was hoping I could leverage `Numeric` somehow

Comment: "Is this really the best way?" Basically yes. You solve the problem by _overloading_, not by a generic. Look at how `+` works in the Swift standard library! There is not one `+` for all numbers; there is a `+` for every separate numeric type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for purposes of syntactical illustration, here's an example of making this a generic and arriving at a Double for all three types:

```
func f<T:Numeric>(_ i: T) {
    var d = 0.0
    switch i {
    case let ii as Int:
        d = Double(ii)
    case let ii as Int32:
        d = Double(ii)
    case let ii as Double:
        d = ii
    default:
        fatalError("oops")
    }
    print(d)
}
```

But whether this is better than overloading is a matter of opinion. In my view, overloading is far better, because with the generic we are letting a bunch of unwanted types in the door. The Numeric contract is a lie. A triple set of overloads for Double, Int, and Int32 would turn the compiler into a source of truth.

Comment: This is a really bad idea because more types could be added that conform to `Numeric` (either from the standard library or from third parties). It would be better to add a concrete overload for every known type that conforms to `Numeric`. Then, you won't get a `fatalError` when trying to pass in a type that's not handled in the switch statement. This should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

> ... because there is no initializer for Double that takes a Generic.

That is not entirely true. There is no initializer taking a `Numeric` argument. But there are generic initializers taking `BinaryInteger` and `BinaryFloatingPoint` arguments, so that two overloads are sufficient:

```
func resetProgressBarChunks<T: BinaryInteger>(originalIterationCount: T) {
    let iCount = Double(originalIterationCount)
    // ...
}

func resetProgressBarChunks<T: BinaryFloatingPoint>(originalIterationCount: T) {
    let iCount = Double(originalIterationCount)
    // ...
}
```

This covers `Double`, `Int`, `Int32` arguments as well as `Float` and all other fixed-size integer types.

Comment: This is clearly the better answer because the function can accept any number type without needing an switch case for each number type.