# Extension for average to return Double from Numeric generic

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

Suppose I create a protocol and structure for a Column of homogeneously typed data:

```
protocol Columnizable {
    associatedtype Item

    var name: String { get }
    var values: [Item] { get }

}

struct Column<T>: Columnizable {

    var name: String
    var values = [T]()

}
```

I would like to create a Protocol extension that allows Numeric to have an `average` function that could compute the average of `values` if the type conforms to `Numeric` protocol- for instance, namely Double and Int

```
extension Columnizable where Item: Numeric {

    func average() -> Double {
        return Double(sum()) / values.count
    }

    func sum() -> Item {
        return values.reduce(0, +)
    }

}
```

My attempt at the `average` function cannot be compiled because of:

`Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(Self.item)'`

Attempts to cast to Double do not work. Any advice for best practices here would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Is there a way to convert any generic Numeric into a Double?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53771879/1187415)

Comment: If I created a `Complex` type that conformed to `Numeric` (which is quite straightforward to do), what would you want to happen here? Thinking through that case will likely lead you to the better answer.

Comment: @MartinR https://stackoverflow.com/a/28288619/2019221

Comment: Thank you guys, @Callam that solution was right on point. I did not know about `BinaryInteger` and `BinaryFloatingPoint`.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use the `BinaryInteger` or `BinaryFloatingPoint` protocols since they can easily be transformed to a `Double`. As @rob napier called out, that a `Complex` type would not be `Double` convertible.

```
extension Columnizable where Item: BinaryInteger {
    var average: Double {
        return Double(total) / Double(values.count)
    }
}

extension Columnizable where Item: BinaryFloatingPoint {
    var average: Item {
        return total / Item(values.count)
    }
}
```

[stackoverflow.com/a/28288619/2019221](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28288619/2019221)

Comment: Make sure to check if the values it is not empty to avoid a division by zero when values is empty.