# How can I convert Generic type SignedNumeric to Float?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm creating some utility class stores numeric values(Int, Float, Double etc...).
It has minimum and maximum value, too.

I need convert a value to percent.

So I write the class as below on Playground:

```
import UIKit

class Series<T: SignedNumeric> {
    let minValue: T
    let maxValue: T
    var datas: [T] = []

    let range: T

    init(minValue: T, maxValue: T) {
        self.minValue = minValue
        self.maxValue = maxValue
        self.range = (maxValue - minValue)
        self.datas = []
    }

    func percent(value: T) -> Float {
        let v: Float = value as! Float
        let m: Float = minValue as! Float
        let r: Float = range as! Float
        return (v - m) / r
    }
}

let s = Series<Int>(minValue: -100, maxValue: 100)
s.datas = [20, 0, 40, -100, 100]
Float(s.datas[0] - s.minValue) / Float(s.range)
Float(s.datas[1] - s.minValue) / Float(s.range)
Float(s.datas[2] - s.minValue) / Float(s.range)
Float(s.datas[3] - s.minValue) / Float(s.range)
Float(s.datas[4] - s.minValue) / Float(s.range)
s.percent(value: s.datas[0]) // ERROR !!!
```

When call s.percent(value: s.datas[0]), it crashed.

How can I write percent() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every `SignedNumeric` can be converted to a `Float`. Recall that to be a `SignedNumeric`, you need to be able to:

- be negative and positive
- be multiplied
- be added and subtracted
- have a magnitude that is `Comparable` and `Numeric`
- can be converted from an integer

The last 4 requirements are all inherited from `Numeric`. We can easily build our own type that can do all those things. Here's a contrived example:

```
struct MyNumber: SignedNumeric, Comparable {
    private var secret: [String]
    private var isNegative: Bool
    private var number: Int { secret.count }
    
    static func *= (lhs: inout MyNumber, rhs: MyNumber) {
        lhs = lhs * rhs
    }
    
    static func * (lhs: MyNumber, rhs: MyNumber) -> MyNumber {
        MyNumber(secret: Array(repeating: "", count: lhs.number * rhs.number), isNegative: lhs.isNegative != rhs.isNegative)
    }
    
    init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        let int = value
        isNegative = int < 0
        secret = Array(repeating: "", count: abs(int))
    }
    
    static func < (lhs: MyNumber, rhs: MyNumber) -> Bool {
        lhs.number < rhs.number
    }
    
    init?<T>(exactly source: T) where T : BinaryInteger {
        guard let int = Int(exactly: source) else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(integerLiteral: int)
    }
    
    var magnitude: MyNumber {
        MyNumber(secret: secret, isNegative: false)
    }
    
    static func - (lhs: MyNumber, rhs: MyNumber) -> MyNumber {
        if lhs < rhs {
            return -(rhs - lhs)
        } else {
            return MyNumber(secret: Array(repeating: "", count: lhs.number - rhs.number))
        }
    }
    
    prefix static func - (operand: MyNumber) -> MyNumber {
        MyNumber(secret: operand.secret, isNegative: !operand.isNegative)
    }
    
    mutating func negate() {
        isNegative.toggle()
    }
    
    init(secret: [String], isNegative: Bool = false) {
        self.secret = secret
        self.isNegative = isNegative
    }
    
    typealias Magnitude = MyNumber
    
    static func + (lhs: MyNumber, rhs: MyNumber) -> MyNumber {
        MyNumber(secret: lhs.secret + rhs.secret)
    }
    
    typealias IntegerLiteralType = Int
    
}
```

How on earth is <insert whoever is doing the conversion here> going to know that, to convert `MyNumber` to `Float`, it has to do `Float(aMyNumber.secret.count)`!? Not to mention that `secret` is private.

On the other hand, `Float.init` does know how to convert `BinaryFloatingPoint`s and `BinaryInteger`s to `Float`, because those protocols define the necessary properties such that `Float.init` can understand how they are represented. For example, `BinaryInteger`s are represented by `words`, which is a `RandomAccessCollection` of `UInt`s, indexed by `Int`s.

I suggest that you only add the `percent` method to types of `Series` where it actually makes sense:

```
extension Series where T : BinaryInteger {
    func percent(value: T) -> Float {
        let v: Float = Float(value)
        let m: Float = Float(minValue)
        let r: Float = Float(range)
        return (v - m) / r
    }
}
```

IMO, it would make sense for any `T : FloatingPoint`, not just `T : BinaryFloatingPoint`:

```
extension Series where T : FloatingPoint {
    func percent(value: T) -> T {
        let v = value
        let m = minValue
        let r = range
        return (v - m) / r
    }
}
```

Since `FloatingPoint` supports division too, you don't need to convert to `Float`!

Comment: Hello, thank you very much!

I added two extensions:

```
extension Series where T : BinaryInteger {
 func percent(value: T) -> Float {
  let v: Float = Float(value)
  let m: Float = Float(minValue)
  let r: Float = Float(range)
  return (v - m) / r
 }
}

extension Series where T : FloatingPoint {
 func percent(value: T) -> T {
  let v = value
  let m = minValue
  let r = range
  return (v - m) / r
 }
}
```

And now I can use percent with Int, Float, Int16... !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65758876/how-can-i-convert-generic-type-signednumeric-to-float#comment116269964_65760275

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much!

I added two extensions:

```
extension Series where T : BinaryInteger {
    func percent(value: T) -> Float {
        let v: Float = Float(value)
        let m: Float = Float(minValue)
        let r: Float = Float(range)
        return (v - m) / r
    }
}

extension Series where T : FloatingPoint {
    func percent(value: T) -> T {
        let v = value
        let m = minValue
        let r = range
        return (v - m) / r
    }
}
```

And now I can use percent() with Int, Float, Int16... !

Comment: Yes but your percent method when used with integers can only return `Float`. You should make it generic and return any `FloatingPoint` type `func percent<F: BinaryFloatingPoint>(value: T) -> F { (F(value) - F(minValue)) / F(range) }`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I have to learn about Generics much more :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65737343/how-can-you-create-a-generic-struct-for-numeric-numbers-that-can-calculate-a-per/65738047#65738047