# How can I make Int conform to BinaryFloatingPoint or Double/CGFloat conform to BinaryInteger?

Tags: swift

I have a function which accept values which conform to **Numeric** protocol, in some point I want convert it to **Int**, **Double** or **CGFloat**.

*the error from xCode:*

```
Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'T' conform to 'BinaryInteger'
```

my function:

```
func test<T: Numeric>(value1: T, value2: T) {

    let someWork = value1 + value2

    let intValue: Int = Int(someWork)               // <<: Here!
    let doubleValue: Double = Double(someWork)      // <<: Here!
    let cgflotValue: CGFloat = CGFloat(someWork)    // <<: Here!

    print(intValue, doubleValue, cgflotValue)

}
```

then I saw the xCode error and updated my function to this down version, I put out **Numeric** because **BinaryInteger** and **BinaryFloatingPoint** conform to **Numeric**

```
func test<T: BinaryInteger & BinaryFloatingPoint>(value1: T, value2: T) {
   
    let someWork = value1 + value2
    
    let intValue: Int = Int(someWork)               // <<: Here: I add BinaryInteger because of Int
    let doubleValue: Double = Double(someWork)      // <<: Here: I add BinaryFloatingPoint because of Double
    let cgflotValue: CGFloat = CGFloat(someWork)    // <<: Here: I add BinaryFloatingPoint because of CGFloat
    
    print(intValue, doubleValue, cgflotValue)
    
}
```

---

**use case:**

```
let testValue1: Int = 2
test(value1: testValue1, value2: testValue1)
```

xCode error for use case:

```
Global function 'test(value1:value2:)' requires that 'Int' conform to 'BinaryFloatingPoint'
```

---

**use case:**

```
let testValue2: Double = 2.0
test(value1: testValue2, value2: testValue2)
```

xCode error for use case:

```
Global function 'test(value1:value2:)' requires that 'Double' conform to 'BinaryInteger'
```

---

How can I make **Int** conform to **BinaryFloatingPoint**?

Or:

How can I make **Double/CGFloat** conform to **BinaryInteger**?

as you see in xCode errors.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53774667/1187415

Comment: So judging by the accepted answer I guess that you never want to mix integers and floating point values as arguments to the function?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I never wanted to mix them, I wanted my function cover all kind of numbers. the errors forced me to add those protocols beside together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add two same functions with different constraint

```
//T: BinaryInteger & BinaryFloatingPoint
func test<T>(value1: T, value2: T) where T: BinaryInteger{
    
    let someWork = value1 + value2
    
    let intValue: Int = Int(someWork)               // <<: Here: I add BinaryInteger because of Int
    let doubleValue: Double = Double(someWork)      // <<: Here: I add BinaryFloatingPoint because of Double
    let cgflotValue: CGFloat = CGFloat(someWork)    // <<: Here: I add BinaryFloatingPoint because of CGFloat
    
    print(intValue, doubleValue, cgflotValue)
    
}
func test<T>(value1: T, value2: T) where T: BinaryFloatingPoint{
    
    let someWork = value1 + value2
    
    let intValue: Int = Int(someWork)               // <<: Here: I add BinaryInteger because of Int
    let doubleValue: Double = Double(someWork)      // <<: Here: I add BinaryFloatingPoint because of Double
    let cgflotValue: CGFloat = CGFloat(someWork)    // <<: Here: I add BinaryFloatingPoint because of CGFloat
    
    print(intValue, doubleValue, cgflotValue)
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. An integer cannot conform to BinaryFloatingPoint and a floating point number cannot conform to BinaryInteger, and you can't make them.

Your function test wants an argument that conforms to both. Int doesn't and Double doesn't.