# Initializer 'xxx' requires that 'Int' conform to 'BinaryFloatingPoint'

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui, binding

I am making a Slider based on a view model, but I am facing this error message `Initializer 'init(value:in:step:label:minimumValueLabel:maximumValueLabel:onEditingChanged:)' requires that 'Int.Stride' (aka 'Int') conform to 'BinaryFloatingPoint'`

[image]

It is strange because converting the integer from view model into Double doesn't quite do the trick.

I found very similar question and read the SO answer ([How can I make Int conform to BinaryFloatingPoint or Double/CGFloat conform to BinaryInteger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68315904/how-can-i-make-int-conform-to-binaryfloatingpoint-or-double-cgfloat-conform-to-b)), but it doesn't seem like I can implementation the solution for my case, probably because I am using `ObservedObject` for the  view model.

If I remove `$` in front of `setInformationVM.elapsedRestTime`, I would see another error message saying `Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Binding<Int>'`

They said "Binding are generally used when there is a need for 2-way communication" - would that mean the Slider needs a way to communicate/update back to the View Model? **Why is it that the Slider was accepting `@State private var xx: Double` for the value in general , but not a simple integer from my view model?**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct SetRestDetailView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var watchDayProgramVM: WatchDayProgramViewModel

    @State var showingLog = false

    var body: some View {

            GeometryReader { geometry in

             ZStack() {
                    (view content removed for readability)
              }

        .sheet(isPresented: $showingLog) {
            
            let setInformatationVM = self.watchDayProgramVM.exerciseVMList[0].sets[2]
            
            setLoggingView(setInformationVM: setInformatationVM, restfullness: 3, stepValue: 10)
        }
        
    }
}
```

***setLoggingView***

```
struct setLoggingView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @ObservedObject var setInformationVM: SetInformationTestClass
    @State var restfullness: Int
    var stepValue: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            let rect = geometry.frame(in: .global)
            
            ScrollView {
                
                VStack(spacing: 5) {
                    
                    Text("Rested  \(Int(setInformationVM.elapsedRestTime)) sec")
                    
                    Slider(value: $setInformationVM.elapsedRestTime,
                           in: 0...setInformationVM.totalRestTime,
                           step: Int.Stride(stepValue),
                           label: {
                        Text("Slider")
                    }, minimumValueLabel: {
                        Text("-\(stepValue)")
                    }, maximumValueLabel: {
                        Text("+\(stepValue)")
                    })
                        .tint(Color.white)
                        .padding(.bottom)

                    Divider()

                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("Restfullness")
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    
                    restfullnessStepper(rect: rect, maxRestFullness: 5, minRestFullness: 1, restfullnessIndex: restfullness)
                
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Update Button Pressed")
                        
                        //TODO
                        //perform further actions to update restfullness metric and elapsed rest time in the viewmodels before dismissing the view, and also update the iOS app by synching the view model.
                        
                        dismiss()
                        
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Update")
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                        }
                    }
                    .cornerRadius(40)
                    
                }
                .border(Color.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
```

***SetInformationTestClass view model***

```
class SetInformationTestClass: ObservableObject {
    
    init(totalRestTime: Int, elapsedRestTime: Int, remainingRestTime: Int, isTimerRunning: Bool) {
        
        self.totalRestTime = totalRestTime
        self.elapsedRestTime = elapsedRestTime
        self.remainingRestTime = remainingRestTime
        
    }
    
    @Published var totalRestTime: Int
    @Published var elapsedRestTime: Int
    @Published var remainingRestTime: Int
```

Comment: "I am making a UISlider" -- `UISlider` is part of UIKit. `Slider`, which is different, and is what you are using, is part of SwiftUI.

Comment: Try making a custom binding - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65737067/14351818

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I can now see where the answer came from and I also updated `UISlider` to `Slider`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom binding variable like :

```swift
let elapsedTime = Binding(
            get: { Double(self.setInformationVM.elapsedRestTime) },
            set: { self.setInformationVM.elapsedRestTime = Int($0) } // Or other custom logic
        )

// then you reference it in the slider like:

Slider(elapsedTime, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks Jake, it worked like a charm, but I removed $ (in front of elapsedTime) as it resulted in error. Creating a binding variable seem rather complicated though.